# Installing Jython on Ubuntu

Tags: jython

1. I downloaded jython_installer-2.5.2.jar from jython.org.
2. Opened the terminal and gave this command:-

`java -jar jython_installer-2.5.2.jar`

1. It was installed in a folder named `jython2.5.2` in the home directory
2. But whenever I open the terminal and give the command `jython` in the terminal I am shown a message saying Jython is not installed.

How can I fix this problem?

I can install Jython using `sudo apt-get install jython`, but the Jython in Ubuntu repositories is 2.2.1 and I want the new version..

Comment: Please read the description of tags before applying them. The tags "linux" and "shell" were wrong. I think that at least the "linux" description changed since the writing of the question though, so maybe that was not your fault.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To install Jython with super user privileges:

```
sudo java -jar jython_installer-2.5.2.jar
```

Select `/usr/local/lib/jython`, then create a symbol link of Jython to /usr/local/bin:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/jython/bin/jython /usr/local/bin/jython
```

Comment: yeah!I read your blog on that and fixed it.. thanks a tonne !

Comment: When I run jython from the bin folder it doesn't start up.  Do I need to change the permissions?  Or do I have to always run ./jython

Comment: I am using ubuntu 15.04 and I can install jython directly by sudo apt-get install jython

Comment: I have the same problem as the poster and Sun Ning's solution didn't help. Despite running sudo java -jar ... my /usr/local/lib does not contain jython

Answer (score 13):

When you type in `jython`, the shell looks for a program with that name in the `PATH`. You should either call the program with its full path:

```
# ~ is an abbreviation for your homedir
~/jython2.5.2/bin/jython
```

or add the directory with the executable to your `PATH`:

```
PATH=$HOME/jython2.5.2/bin:$PATH
```

If you want the latter to persist across terminal sessions, add it to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it explains why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ubuntu 19.04, you can install with apt

```
sudo apt install jython
```

Comment: Works on 18.04.3 also!